# invalid VIProductVersion format, should be X.X.X.X

Tags: nsis

Can VIProductVersion contain string??
I am setting 2017x.1.1.0 as product version so getting invalid format error. 
is there any way to resolve this error?

Thanks,
Deepak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to resolve this is to provide the version string in the correct format. Your version string contains a letter, but it can only contain numbers.

Windows convention for version strings is `<major version>.<minor version>.<build number>.<revision>`.

Comment: Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 4):

The version number can be stored in two different ways in the PE version resource.

`VIProductVersion` sets the version number in the fixed block called [VS_FIXEDFILEINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646997(VS.85).aspx) and can only contain numbers.

You can also add string information with `VIAddVersionKey` and these are normally displayed in the UI.

```
VIProductVersion "1.2.3.4"
VIAddVersionKey FileVersion "1.2hello.3.4" ; Displayed at the top of the version tab on <= WinXP
VIAddVersionKey ProductVersion "1.2.world3.4"
```